# How to get an Android Switch status from another class?

Tags: java, android, get, android-widget

i'm working with a RecyclerView wich has a Switch that lets the user organize the list from A to Z when the switch is on, and from Z to A when it is off, in order to implement the OnClick method i need to now the position of each element, but the element could be in two different positions (depending on the sorting chosen by the user) so in order to know where the element is, i need to know the status of the Switch from the class that implements the OnClick method.

This is my Switch-sorting implementation :

```
@Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                if(isChecked){
                    switchStatus.setText("Sorting alphabetically");


                    Collections.sort(categories, new Comparator<Categories>() {
                        @Override
                        public int compare(Categories lhs, Categories rhs) {
                            return lhs.title.compareTo(rhs.title);
                        }
                    });


                    ca.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }else{
                    switchStatus.setText("Sorting by popularity");

                    Collections.sort(categories, new Comparator<Categories>() {
                        @Override
                        public int compare(Categories rhs, Categories lhs) {
                            return lhs.title.compareTo(rhs.title);
                        }
                    });

                ca.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

            }
        });


        //check the current state before we display the screen
        if(categoriesSortingSwitch.isChecked()){
            switchStatus.setText("Sorting alphabetically");


            Collections.sort(categories, new Comparator<Categories>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(Categories lhs, Categories rhs) {
                    return lhs.title.compareTo(rhs.title);
                }
            });


        }
        else {
            switchStatus.setText("Sorting by popularity");

            Collections.sort(categories, new Comparator<Categories>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(Categories rhs, Categories lhs) {
                    return lhs.title.compareTo(rhs.title);
                }
            });

        }

    }

//I CREATED THIS METHOD THINKING IN USING IT IN THE OTHER CLASS TO GET THE STATUS
   public boolean getSwitchstatus(){

        if(categoriesSortingSwitch.isChecked()){

            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }
```

And this is the method of the other class where i need to get the status :

```
@Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final Intent intent;

            int position = getAdapterPosition();
            if (position==0){

                if(/** find a way to see if it is on or off and if it is on do this**/){

                intent =  new Intent(context, nose.class);
                context.startActivity(intent);
                }
                else/** if it is off**/{

                }

            }
        }
```

In resume, i need to find a way to get the status of the switch so i can tell the position of the element.

Thanks very much.

Comment: Use a SharedPreference. Save/Create the data (the Shared) when the switch is ON and remove it when is OFF. If ON, check the SharedPreference (you could use a tag for that) and if match, do wherever you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to MkiiSoft advice this is what i did and works perfectly :

```
    @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                    if(isChecked){
                        switchStatus.setText("Sorting alphabetically");


                        Collections.sort(categories, new Comparator<Categories>() {
                            @Override
                            public int compare(Categories lhs, Categories rhs) {
                                return lhs.title.compareTo(rhs.title);
                            }
                        });


                        ca.notifyDataSetChanged();


//JUST ADDED THIS SHARED PREFERENCE WITH THE STRINGS ("it's","on") WHEN THE SWITCH IS ON

                        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                        editor.putString("it's","on");
                        editor.apply();

                    }else{
                        switchStatus.setText("Sorting by popularity");

                        Collections.sort(categories, new Comparator<Categories>() {
                            @Override
                            public int compare(Categories rhs, Categories lhs) {
                                return lhs.title.compareTo(rhs.title);
                            }
                        });

                    ca.notifyDataSetChanged();

    //JUST ADDED THIS SHARED PREFERENCE WITH THE STRINGS ("it's","off") WHEN THE SWITCH IS OFF

                        SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                        editor.putString("it's", "off");
                        editor.apply();
                    }

                }
            });
```

Then in Class where i needed to now the status of the switch i simply compared the strings and based on the matching or missmatching of the strings oppened a different Activity, this way :

```
    public void onClick(View v) {
                final Intent intent;

                int position = getAdapterPosition();

                SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
                String onoff = preferences.getString("it's", "");

//IF IT IS ON DO THIS
                if(onoff.equalsIgnoreCase("on"))
                {
                    if (position==0){

                        intent =  new Intent(context, nose.class);
                        context.startActivity(intent);
                    }

    //IF IT IS OFF DO THIS
                } else if (onoff.equalsIgnoreCase("off")){

                    if (position==0){

                        intent =  new Intent(context, nose2.class);
                        context.startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
            }
```